# JQuery Data Table OnClick tr td :NOT tr th

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables, onclick, row

I have a JQuery Data table and I have an onClick function that collects all the table row data and displays a modal... That works fine. The problem persists when I click on the Table Header to sort the rows, the modal pops up Because its inside a table row... My question is how can I allow TR TD to work but not TR TH?

I have tried the :NOT selected for TH it didnt work

```
 $('#jqueryDataTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {

            //This is the selected data from the row
            selectedData = table.row(this).data();
            //Display a MODAL with this information

 });
```

I expect when I click the header to sort the modal and on click doesn't trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Add the event listener to the tbody tag's table rows
//This will eliminate the problem of clicking a table header as it is contained
//In the thead tag
 $('#jqueryDataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {

            //This is the selected data from the row
            selectedData = table.row(this).data();
            //Display a MODAL with this information

 });
```